Saving Tutor LMS plugin courses as WordPress Blog Posts in Database
I am using Tutor LMS plugin. I am changing my WordPress theme and in my new theme i do not want to use Tutor LMS plugin.
My uploaded courses are very simple, similar to a blog post with no student registration, quiz or course curricula.
I know PHP & MySQL programming. I want to move all of my created courses with Tutor LMS plugin to my blog posts.
I wonder if I can do changes in my WordPress database or coding to save all of my courses as blog posts instead of manually copy them one by one.
Lastly, I do not want to use any migration tools or plugin
I appreciate your help

If your courses are custom post types then you could probably do some dangerous search and replace in the database. I'm not familiar with the plugin so that's about as much as I can help.

I just figure it out on db. Changed the post type and updated the post url...everything works fine...save me hours...Thx
